# How to interface with blender using IPython from terminal?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there any way to interface with blender using IPython in blender 2.68? I have tried many many options over the past couple of days and none of them have worked for me...

The best option for me would be if I could use IPython in the terminal I initiated blender with.

I have tried using `IPython.embed` with no success, and I also have tried [**this**](http://pythonide.blogspot.com/2009/03/resumable-ipython-inside-blender_31.html), but I can't get it to work with blender 2.68a.

Perhaps there is a way to start an instance of blender from within an IPython session?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but from what I can tell, `blender --python-console` does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply run this in a text editor

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

it's even in blenders [official documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/info_tips_and_tricks.html#drop-into-a-python-interpreter-in-your-script).

#### Note:

This will lock Blenders UI and prevent any redraws or user input while the console runs. You can start IPython in the terminal, execute some commands, then Ctrl+D, to exit the IPython and use Blender again.

There is no convenient way to avoid this.

Comment: OK, I've tried running a script containing this at startup, but I get "RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin"

Comment: @user1276, define *"running a script containing this at startup"*, I tried saving these 2 lines in a script, then running: `blender --python test_ipython.py` and ipython gave me a prompt in the terminal I started blender from.

Comment: Yes, this is the command I tried exactly, except when I tried it with these two lines only I received "ImportError: No module named IPython". To solve this, I have three lines appending my local python site-packages to the blender python sys.path. I also included the lines mentioned in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: I tried it without the other lines from the documentation and am given a prompt, but now blender runs with a completely blank screen... When I ctrl-D out of ipython, blender loads the gui into the window... Any ideas, ideasman? :)

Comment: @user1276 *"without the other lines from the documentation"*, Please try to be specific or it becomes hard to provide useful feedback.

Comment: Quite sorry, without these:
    `import code \n
    namespace = globals().copy() \n
    namespace.update(locals()) \n
    code.interact(local=namespace)`

Comment: When I run in debug mode, here are the two debug logs printed to the terminal between exiting ipython and the blender gui loading: 

    recalcob Cube  
    recalcdata Cube

Comment: Not sure why this would fail: suggest to, install fresh blender, backup / remove your user preferences. Remove the "python" directory in the fresh blender install (forces use of system python), then try running blender from a console and running this in blenders text editor `import IPython; IPython.embed()`. Troubleshooting this stuff remotely is tricky but think this has the greatest chance of working.

Comment: OK, thank you so much ideasman42! I really appreciate all your help on this. I will mark this question as closed because you have thoroughly answered the solution that will likely work for most people. I have started a [new question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2949/blender-does-not-fully-load-when-running-python-script-at-boot) with the specific details of my problem, and I will proceed in the manner that you have suggested.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming upon this question in 2020, I had a similar want and wanted to use Blender from a Jupyter Notebook.

I made a Jupyter Kernel to do this for Blender 2.8 [here](https://github.com/cameronfr/BlenderKernel). It uses `asyncio` so the Blender UI is *not* locked when using the kernel.

Comment: Brilliant. Going to try set it up this weekend :)

Comment: We created a sample notebook available [here](https://github.com/Scherlac/blender_notebook), and there is an installer for this blender kernel [here](https://github.com/cheng-chi/blender_notebook). Have fun!

Comment: See also [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208981/113375)

Answer (score 0):

Start Blender with a threading that run `IPython.embed()`

```bash
blender --python-expr '__import__("threading").Timer(0, __import__("IPython").embed).start()'

# It won't lock Blender UI.
# Have fun with IPython in blender!
```

If not install IPython:

````bash
# Get pip: equl to /blender-path/2.xx/python/bin/python3.7m -m ensurepip
blender -b --python-expr "__import__('ensurepip')._bootstrap()" 

# Update pip toolchain
blender -b --python-expr "__import__('pip._internal')._internal.main(['install', '-U', 'pip', 'setuptools', 'wheel'])"

# pip install IPython (or any package)
blender -b --python-expr "__import__('pip._internal')._internal.main(['install', 'IPython'])"
```
````