# Blender does not fully load when running python script at boot

Tags: python, command-line

I am using a start up script to run IPython from the terminal I started blender from. To do this, I have a script containing the following:

```
import bpy

#For importing from my local python environment
import sys
ps = ['','/usr/bin','/usr/lib/python3.3',
'/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu','/usr/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
for p in ps:
    sys.path.append(p)

import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

When I attempt to run the script with:

```
blender2 --debug-all --python run_ipython.py
```

The ipython interpreter is brought up, a window is created, but nothing except gray space or glitchy nonsense is found inside of the window. However, when I ctrl-D out of ipython, blender finishes loading as expected and runs as normal.

The following is what is printed to the terminal *after* I close IPython.

```
bpy.ops.wm.splash()
WM_operator_last_properties_store: storing properties for 'WM_OT_splash'
ghost_event_proc: window 1 state = normal
wm_window_make_drawable: set drawable 1
ghost_event_proc: ghost redraw 1
ghost_event_proc: ghost redraw 1
recalcob Cube
recalcdata Cube
ED_screen_refresh: set screen
```

I can only assume that it is the debug log from whatever actions are loading the rest of blender. Here's the question: How can I reproduce what is happening in the above lines so that I can fully load blender with ipython in the terminal?

Comment: Please define "fully loaded" - Initializing blender is complex and there are many details but its hard to know which is important in your case.

Comment: Voted to close, this question asks about API details which are unrelated to the real problem (XY-issue). I've updated my answer to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/use-the-terminal-i-called-blender-from-as-my-console so this question isn't needed.