# How can I use blender's python API from a Ipython terminal or Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to have a python notebook running on my localhost:8000 that i can execute `bpy` scripts with... and see the resulting change in my other monitor which is running blender.

Normally, I would have to import a script into the "Scripting - TextEditor" view and hit "run script".  Is there a way to bypass this interface?

Comment: This one maybe? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167390/73532

Answer (score 5):

One of the most important things to be aware of is installing the correct version of the tools:

Using the current 2.91 Blender version we should use Python 3.7. We can install that using Anaconda3 2020.02 from [exe](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86.exe), [list of packages](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/oldpkglists/).

After that we need to install the blender kernel from [here](https://github.com/cheng-chi/blender_notebook), using the following command in anaconda terminal:

```py
python -m pip install blender_notebook
blender_notebook install --blender-exec="C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\blender.exe"
```

Now, when we start Jupyter Notebook we can select blender kernel.

First, you need to import the Blender specific library `bpy`:

```py
# blender related imports
import bpy
```

After that, we are able to use many examples, already available out there.

I've made an example Jupyter Notebook on this topic, available [here](https://github.com/Scherlac/blender_notebook)

See the discussion and plans on updating blender's python version [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/python-3-8/8845).

Update:

Blender 2.93: Python was upgraded to version 3.9.1. [link](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.93/Python_API)