# Blender in a Jupyter notebook that will be available online

Tags: external-applications

I would like to use Blender in a Jupyter notebook, something like that:
https://github.com/panzi/blender_ipython

I mostly want it to be available online, using a service like Binder.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags. Unless there are many questions that would benefit from a new tag, it is best not to create new ones. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208981/113375)