Blender - Jupyter Notebook workflow
I was looking for a way to work with Blender and Jupyter Notebook in a side-by-side configuration, where I compose a scene in Jupyter using bpy and it is displayed in the Blender window.  In the Blender help file topic, "Using Blender from the Command Line", it seemed like this should be possible.  It gives "For Python development, to see the output of the print() function" as one of the use cases.
Background tasks work fine (i.e. creating a scene & rendering it to a png, movie, etc.) but I haven't been able to get anything working with an active Blender front-end.
With Blender open, I created a Jupyter notebook and tried something like this:
import bpy

# Clear existing objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

# Add a cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=20, location=(0, 0, 0))

# Check if the cube is created
print("Cube created in Blender.")

It runs without an error and prints, "Cube created in Blender" but nothing happens in the Blender window.
But if I create a scene and add a camera, I can render that scene with code like this:
output = 'D:/path/output.png'
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

I'm on Windows and using Blender 4.2.2 LTS.  My Python environment has Python v3.11.0 and bpy v4.2.0.
Can a Jupyter Notebook interact with an active Blender window or is the API only suitable for background tasks?

I don't know Jupyter Notebook. How do you run the bpy. code in it? Have you installed Blender as Python module? Your first script uses bpy.ops. operators. Some of them need UI editors like the 3D viewport. Have you tried to create the cube with the bmesh module?

I have installed Blender as Python module and the version matches the installed Blender application [well maybe.  the application is 4.2.2, the Python module is 4.2.0].  I just tried using bmesh with the same result.  The script runs fine, and I can render the scene using the bpy module from Jupyter Notebook, but still nothing is shown in the Blender application.

I think this is a very similar problem to the following:
How to interface with blender using IPython from terminal?
Especially the following answer is probaby what you are looking for:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167390/205751
And here is a repo that was one of the answers
https://github.com/Scherlac/blender_notebook
It even has a Pypi wheel. Just install the module and specify the executable location:
pip install blender_notebook
blender_notebook install --blender-exec="c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\blender.exe"


I think these references are obsolete.  They refer to Blender version 2.x. It seems like something has changed with current version of Blender that is preventing the Blender python module from running in the foreground (every background operation I've tested works, but nothing seems to allow me to open a Blender window and see changes the impact of API calls made from Jupyter).  If anyone has this working with current version of Blender, please share

One of the answers in the links was suggesting to use the following:https://github.com/cameronfr/BlenderKernel

Thanks @bepop_artist for the tip!!  It's now working for me.  I think the winning formula was following the instructions here:  https://github.com/cheng-chi/blender_notebook.  The trickiest part for me was figuring out how to launch the kernel correctly from VS Code, but I need to do some more investigation before I can comment further.
